# Foundation - foundation.topbar.js not found

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm trying to create a top bar in Foundation according to this page: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/topbar.html . The page says I need `/js/foundation.topbar.js`. I can't seem to find this file on my computer, nor can I find it on GitHub. How can I get the file?

Kind regards,

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topbar is not part of Foundation 6 anymore. It is just part of Foundation Sites 5.
See https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html for the current / new solution.

Foundation 5 is not actively supported anymore.

Comment: I used the code from that page and it works! Thank you very much!